# identify missing files in a folder

Tags: files, regular-expression, filenames

I have a process creating the following files, which share a similar pattern.

```
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
.
.
.
file_1000.txt
.
.
.
file_1901.txt
file_1902.txt
```

But, there are only `1890` files in the folder. I would like to know if there is a way to identify the missing files from the list of files sharing a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..2000}
do
    file_name="file_${i}.txt"
    if [ ! -f ${file_name} ]
    then
        echo "${file_name} not exists.."
    fi
done
```

---

```
for i in {1..2000};do file_name="file_${i}.txt"; [ -f ${file_name} ] || echo "${file_name} not exists"; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the working solution. Any one-liners possible?

Comment: added one-liner